# Show range of lines with PHP

Tags: php, range

To show content from a file I use: `<?php echo file_get_contents("file.php"); ?>`.

How can I show only lines from 10 to 23 of `file.php`?

Tried without success:

```
$lines = file('file.php');

$range = array_merge($lines,range(10, 23)); 

foreach ($range as $line_num => $line) {
  echo $line."\n";
}
```

Comment: How big is file? "Tried without success:" --- have you tried to read the documentations for the functions you use?

Comment: and what `array_merge` does? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) instead:

```
$range = array_slice($lines, 10, 13);
```

Or, if you want the line numbers to stay from 10 to 23, just loop like that and avoid the copy:

```
for($line = 10; $line <= 23; $line++) {
    echo $line, ': ', $lines[$line - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$range = array_slice($lines, 10, 13, true);
                                      ^--- required, as long as you want to
                                         have the original line numbers available
```

Documentation: http://php.net/array_slice